# PayPal Rest API - 401 when creating an invoice

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal

I'm getting a 401 error when I try to create a PayPal invoice. I'm using the nodejs REST API:

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs

I did a quick test with the create invoice sample, changing the id and secret in the configure.js to those my app in sandbox. I get the 401 when this happens as well. The app is setup to allow invoice actions (it's in the scope parameter when I request the token), is there something else I need to enable?

I contacted PayPal technical support, they said to contact PayPal MTS. When I contacted them they said to contact technical support... I'm assuming it's something account related as that's the only thing I changed in the sample.

---

Edit 2014-09-17

I can get a token with curl:

{"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing openid https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card","access_token":"A015QDaSWWVrhK.FNSZVZd-vDGflSm.g1H.4PnDeXaYDFqo","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":28800}

I'm using the samples from github (configure.js and invoice/create.js specifically) the only thing I changed was the client and secret in configure.

Comment: In the 401 message that is returned to you, is there a detailed error message? Also, do you get back any debug-id from the request? https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs#debugging

Comment: Nothing detailed beyond authorization error: { name: 'AUTHORIZATION_ERROR',
  message: 'Authorization error occurred.',
  debug_id: '036d6f583b45b',
  httpStatusCode: 401 }

Comment: This behavior is consistent whether you use a curl request or the sdk? Also post your full request/response from getting token to making request.

Comment: Added to the original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The e-mail in the request was the issue. It worked with the sample because it was the e-mail associated with the app. Changing the config id and secret to mine wasn't enough, the e-mail needed to be changed to mine as well.

Comment: I have simillar problem although I am using python and requests module. Which email you had to change? 

I get something like: {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","debug_id":"ab4350a8ee111"}

Comment: The one in the merchant_info object: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/invoice/create.js

Answer (score 2):

Just spent a couple of hours trying to solve this very issue. The answer Dave gave above led me on the right track.

The "merchant e-mail" in the request has to be the Paypal Sandbox Developer Account associated with the REST API app in question. I hope this helps someone.

Below is a screenshot highlighting the property in Visual Studios and PostMan.

[image]